# I purchased a ticket with foreign passport but now I have a citizen Passport, What to do?

Tags: tickets, dual-nationality

I need your advice. 
I purchased a ticket with my Brazilian passport in January, and since then I received my Australian Passport that has a different 'first name', 'last name'. I called Qantas to change the name, and they said I would have to cancel my flight, get the refund, and purchase a new ticket with the current available price. They said that the Qantas ticket flight is not transferable, even though I'm not transferring the ticket, I'm changing my name to match the Australia Passport. Any advice? What can and should I do?

Comment: Related:  [Two passports, two names, one name on the ticket](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49710/two-passports-two-names-one-name-on-the-ticket?rq=1)

Comment: My best guess is that if you have two passports with similar names, one of those names matches the name the ticket, and the pictures in the passports are both clearly you, then the airline will not have a problem with it.  But I'm not sure enough about this to make it an answer.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This has two different names.

Comment: @user56513:  One of the cases discussed in [the top-rated answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/52101/31165) in the duplicate is "Case 2: Different names, dual citizenship OK".

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I noticed that. However I believe it is well established here that duplicate is in reference to the question, and not the answer I.e two questions are not duplicate just because they have the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Brazilian passport to board the plane, and then use the Australian passport at immigration. I have been in the same situation, I booked a flight to Italy with my Aussie passport, but when I got there I used my Italian passport just fine. I’m not sure if you have to show evidence of a Visa to check-in staff, or if showing them your Aussie passport is enough, I would call the airline about that.

Comment: Note that the OP will need to prove to the airline that Australia will let them in.  If they simply present their Brazilian passport without an Australian visa in it, the airline will probably not let them board, as Brazilian citizens require a visa to visit Australia.  (This is not the case for Italian citizens.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That does seem like the problem at hand, maybe showing his second passport would act as proof of being able to enter? I think he should call about that.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert don't Italian citizens require eVisitor authorization?  Mgrande465, have you checked in for flights to Australia with your Italian passport without having eVisitor authorization? If so, did you do that without showing your Australian passport?

Comment: @phoog unfortunately not, I have only done it the other way around, and there is no authorisation needed to go to the EU with my Aussie passport